# Why is the mutual information nonzero for two independent variables

Tags: information-theory

Suppose we have two independent variables **X** and **Y**. Intuitively the mutual information, **I(X,Y)**, between the two should be zero, as knowing one tells us nothing about the other.

The math behind this also checks out from the definition of the mutual information (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information).

Now let us compute it actually. First generate two simple random vectors of length 10 in R:

```
X=sample(seq(1,100),10)
Y=sample(seq(1000,10000),10)
```

I got these:

```
X={3, 35, 93, 13, 90, 89, 34, 97, 49, 82}
Y={7611, 5041, 2612, 4273, 6714, 4391, 1000, 6657, 8736, 2443}
```

The mutual information can be expressed with the entropies **H(X)**, **H(Y)** and the joint entropy between **X** and **Y**, **H(X,Y)**

```
I(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y) - H(X,Y)
```

Moreover

```
H(X) = -10*[(1/10)*log(1/10)] = log(10)
```

since each observation occurs only once and thus has a frequency of 1/10 of occurring. The maximum entropy for a random variable of length N is log(N) so this calculation checks out.

Similarly

```
H(Y) = log(10)
```

The joint entropy is similar to the individual entropies but this time we count the frequencies of **pairs** occurring. For example the pair **{X=3,Y=7611}** occurs only once out of a total of 10 paired observations, hence it has a frequency of 1/10. Therefore:

```
H(X,Y) = -10*[(1/10)*log(1/10)] = log(10)
```

since each paired observation occurs only once.

So

```
I(X,Y) = log(10) + log(10) - log(10) = log(10)
```

which is clearly non-zero. This is also the result that various R packages (e.g. infotheo) produce.

The question is where is the mistake in my thinking? Why is **I(X,Y)** not zero?

Comment: I don't understand what are you doing here. $X$ , as a random variable, is a single integer value, of which you generate 10 samples? Why do you generate it by sampling from a sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how in the formula of Mutual Information there are probabilities, not frequences. A frequency is just an approximation of probability, and with a sample so small, you get very inaccurate approximations, hence the result.

In order to calculate the Mutual Information of a discrete random variable X uniformly distributed over [1,100] and an independent random variable Y uniformly distributed over [1000, 10000], you calculate:

H(X) = -100*[(1/100)*log(1/100)] = log(100)

H(Y) = -9001*[(1/9001)*log(1/9001)] = log(9001)

H(X,Y) = -(900100)*[(1/900100)*log(1/900100)] = log(900100)

I(X,Y) = log(100) + log(9001) - log(900100) = 0

What you have actually calculated is the Mutual Information of two discrete random variables with the following joint probability distribution:

p(3, 7611) = 0.1

p(35, 5041) = 0.1

p(93, 2612) = 0.1

p(13, 4273) = 0.1

p(90, 6714) = 0.1

p(89, 4391) = 0.1

p(34, 1000) = 0.1

p(97, 6657) = 0.1

p(49, 8736) = 0.1

p(82, 2443) = 0.1

These variables are not independent; in fact, knowing one of the values is sufficient to find the other one. That is why their Mutual Information is not zero.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you were on the correct path but you did a small mistake while calculating the joint entropy. There will be 100 unique pairs of symbols so the joint entropy will be $\log 100$, that will make the mutual information equal to zero.

Comment: Which would mean that all R packages that compute this do it wrong. I am somewhat skeptical about that.

Comment: More precisely, I don't think we have 100 pairs.We only have the pairs we actually **observe**, i.e. we have the pair {X=3,Y=7611},but not the pair {X=3,Y=5041}. Alternatively if you want to count all possible permutations as number of pairs, then the probability of observing the pair {X=3,Y=5041} is 0, because we never observed it in the data.
I think the calculation is correct, i.e. mutual info should not be 0 **after** you observe data, since the mere fact of observing something is information. So this points to a conceptual misunderstanding on my side, which I am not perfectly clear about.